# Converting String to Array with php

Tags: php, arrays, string

Recently I have been having an issue with converting a string to an array. My method might not be the best or I'm just missing something. Any help would be nice.

My array (this cannot be changed):

```
$lic = "[[`license_civ_driver`,1],[`license_civ_boat`,0],[`license_civ_pilot`,0],[`license_civ_trucking`,0],[`license_civ_gun`,1],[`license_civ_dive`,0],[`license_civ_home`,0],[`license_civ_oil`,0],[`license_civ_diamond`,0],[`license_civ_salt`,0],[`license_civ_sand`,0],[`license_civ_iron`,0],[`license_civ_copper`,0],[`license_civ_cement`,0],[`license_civ_medmarijuana`,0],[`license_civ_cocaine`,0],[`license_civ_heroin`,0],[`license_civ_marijuana`,0],[`license_civ_rebel`,0]]";
```

The result I need:

```
'license_civ_driver' => '1', 'license_civ_boat' => '0', 'license_civ_pilot' => '0', 'license_civ_trucking' => '0', 'license_civ_gun' => '1', 'license_civ_dive' => '0', 'license_civ_home' => '0', 'license_civ_oil' => '0', 'license_civ_diamond' => '0', 'license_civ_salt' => '0', 'license_civ_sand' => '0', 'license_civ_iron' => '0', 'license_civ_copper' => '0', 'license_civ_cement' => '0', 'license_civ_medmarijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_cocaine' => '0', 'license_civ_heroin' => '0', 'license_civ_marijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_rebel' => '0'
```

Here is what I'm currently doing

```
$lic = str_replace('[', "", $lic);
$lic = str_replace(']', "", $lic);
$lic = str_replace('"', "", $lic);
$lic = str_replace(',1', " => '1'", $lic);
$lic = str_replace(',0', " => '0'", $lic);
// $licenses = str_replace('0,', " ", $licenses);
$lic = str_replace(',', ', ', $lic);
$lic = str_replace('`', "'", $lic);
```

The result:

```
'license_civ_driver' => '1', 'license_civ_boat' => '0', 'license_civ_pilot' => '0', 'license_civ_trucking' => '0', 'license_civ_gun' => '1', 'license_civ_dive' => '0', 'license_civ_home' => '0', 'license_civ_oil' => '0', 'license_civ_diamond' => '0', 'license_civ_salt' => '0', 'license_civ_sand' => '0', 'license_civ_iron' => '0', 'license_civ_copper' => '0', 'license_civ_cement' => '0', 'license_civ_medmarijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_cocaine' => '0', 'license_civ_heroin' => '0', 'license_civ_marijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_rebel' => '0'
```

However when converting this to an array the string it is classed as 1 value like this:

```
$lic = array("'license_civ_driver' => '1', 'license_civ_boat' => '0', 'license_civ_pilot' => '0', 'license_civ_trucking' => '0', 'license_civ_gun' => '1', 'license_civ_dive' => '0', 'license_civ_home' => '0', 'license_civ_oil' => '0', 'license_civ_diamond' => '0', 'license_civ_salt' => '0', 'license_civ_sand' => '0', 'license_civ_iron' => '0', 'license_civ_copper' => '0', 'license_civ_cement' => '0', 'license_civ_medmarijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_cocaine' => '0', 'license_civ_heroin' => '0', 'license_civ_marijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_rebel' => '0'");
```

However, I want it each value to be separated like this:

```
    $lic = array('license_civ_driver' => '1', 'license_civ_boat' => '0', 'license_civ_pilot' => '0', 'license_civ_trucking' => '0', 'license_civ_gun' => '1', 'license_civ_dive' => '0', 'license_civ_home' => '0', 'license_civ_oil' => '0', 'license_civ_diamond' => '0', 'license_civ_salt' => '0', 'license_civ_sand' => '0', 'license_civ_iron' => '0', 'license_civ_copper' => '0', 'license_civ_cement' => '0', 'license_civ_medmarijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_cocaine' => '0', 'license_civ_heroin' => '0', 'license_civ_marijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_rebel' => '0');
```

Is anyone able to help me with this issue?
(I can provide any more informated you need, this is my first post so sorry if im brief.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    $string ='license_civ_driver' => '1', 'license_civ_boat' => '0', 'license_civ_pilot' => '0', 'license_civ_trucking' => '0', 'license_civ_gun' => '1', 'license_civ_dive' => '0', 'license_civ_home' => '0', 'license_civ_oil' => '0', 'license_civ_diamond' => '0', 'license_civ_salt' => '0', 'license_civ_sand' => '0', 'license_civ_iron' => '0', 'license_civ_copper' => '0', 'license_civ_cement' => '0', 'license_civ_medmarijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_cocaine' => '0', 'license_civ_heroin' => '0', 'license_civ_marijuana' => '0', 'license_civ_rebel' => '0'
   $arr =  explode(',',$string);
 print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply exploding with comma will make it indexed array not associative array. So when fetching values from indexed array with key you will need to do some more operations. Example

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'license_civ_driver' => '1'
    [1] =>  'license_civ_boat' => '0'
    [2] =>  'license_civ_pilot' => '0'
    [3] =>  'license_civ_trucking' => '0'
    [4] =>  'license_civ_gun' => '1'
    [5] =>  'license_civ_dive' => '0'
    [6] =>  'license_civ_home' => '0'
    [7] =>  'license_civ_oil' => '0'
    [8] =>  'license_civ_diamond' => '0'
    [9] =>  'license_civ_salt' => '0'
    [10] =>  'license_civ_sand' => '0'
    [11] =>  'license_civ_iron' => '0'
    [12] =>  'license_civ_copper' => '0'
    [13] =>  'license_civ_cement' => '0'
    [14] =>  'license_civ_medmarijuana' => '0'
    [15] =>  'license_civ_cocaine' => '0'
    [16] =>  'license_civ_heroin' => '0'
    [17] =>  'license_civ_marijuana' => '0'
    [18] =>  'license_civ_rebel' => '0'
)
```

So, you can try this out.

```
$lic = explode(",", $lic);
$requried = [];

foreach ($lic as $temp) {
   $t = explode('=>', str_replace("'", "", trim($temp)));

    $required[$t[0]] = $t[1];
}
```

Now `$required` contains the associative array whose **key** and **value** you can get using `foreach` loop

Comment: Thank you as well, I'll try your method.